# Insert List of images in excel of given path in the other column in mac

Tags: excel, vba, macos, image

I want to insert images in cell taking the path from the other cell values. like [image]

i have VBA Code after running this code image not able to display in cell.

```
Sub Picture()
Dim pictname As String
Dim pastehere As Range
Dim pasterow As Long
Dim x As Long
Dim lastrow As Long

lastrow = Worksheets("sheet1").Range("B2").CurrentRegion.Rows.Count
x = 2
For x = 2 To lastrow
Set pastehere = Cells(x, 1)
pasterow = pastehere.Row
Cells(pasterow, 1).Select 'This is where picture will be inserted

pictname = Cells(x, 2) 'This is the picture name
ActiveSheet.Pictures.Insert("/Users/user_name/60101394868/" & pictname).Select 'Path to where pictures are stored

With Selection

.Left = Cells(pasterow, 1).Left
.Top = Cells(pasterow, 1).Top

.ShapeRange.LockAspectRatio = msoFalse
.ShapeRange.Height = 80#
.ShapeRange.Width = 80#
.ShapeRange.Rotation = 0#
End With

Next

End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: `"/Users/abhaykumar/...` You said MAC... Is the path correct?

Comment: @SiddharthRout yes this is the correct path